# Easy admin bundle and url rewriting for access control

Tags: php, symfony, url-rewriting, acl, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using Easy Admin Bundle for Symfony 2 and I have problem to setup ACL in security.yml. It doesn't take into account url parameters so I need to rewrite URL.

Current:

```
.../admin/?entity=User&action=list&menuIndex=0&submenuIndex=-1
```

Here is what I need:

```
.../admin/User/?action=list&menuIndex=0&submenuIndex=-1
```

After that is easy to setup ACL from:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

To something like:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/files/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/user/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Or:

```
access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_USER }
            - { path: ^/files/, role: ROLE_USER }
            - { path: ^/user/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Or maybe is there some different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the solution:

https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1076

Just edit your config.yml, like is in an example:

```
BlogEntry:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\BlogEntry
            permissions:
                list:  ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EDITOR']
                create:  ['ROLE_ADMIN']
                edit:  ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EDITOR']
                delete:  ['ROLE_ADMIN']
```

And then overwrite the EasyAdmin AdminController and overwrite the indexAction method:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as EasyAdminController;

class AdminController extends EasyAdminController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="easyadmin")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->initialize($request);

        if (null === $request->query->get('entity')) {
            return $this->redirectToBackendHomepage();
        }

        $action = $request->query->get('action', 'list');
        if (!$this->isActionAllowed($action)) {
            throw new ForbiddenActionException(array('action' => $action, 'entity' => $this->entity['name']));
        }

        if (isset($this->entity['permissions'][$action])) {
            $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($this->entity['permissions'][$action]);
        }

        return $this->executeDynamicMethod($action.'<EntityName>Action');
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in the last version of EasyAdmin (v1.16.10 for me), `executeDynamicMethod()` and `redirectToBackendHomepage()` methods are private. 
You have to copy them into your child class to make it works so.